# Error in h(simpleError(msg, call))

Tags: r

Estoy haciendo mi trabajo de fin de master y es la primera vez que uso R. Debo aplicar una estimacion por Maxima verosimilitud.
El error que obtengo es:

```
 - Error in h(simpleError(msg, call)) : 
         error in evaluating the argument 'object' in selecting a method for function 'logLik': only defined on a data frame with all numeric
   variables
```

Esto es paso a paso lo que he ido aplicando, el error se genera en el ultimo comando:

```
Datos <- read.table("C:/Users/andre/Documents/Master Consultoria Economica/TFM/Base tfm.csv",header=TRUE, sep=";", na.strings="NA", dec=",", strip.white=TRUE, fileEncoding="UTF-8-BOM")

summary(Datos)
sapply(Datos, class)
attach(Datos)

##DEFINIR VARIABLES##

Ct=data.frame(VarCredito)

X1=data.frame(FonDisp,
              TAE,
              TasaMora,
              PrecioPet,
              IDEAC)
X2=data.frame(TAE,
              Paro,
              IPIM,
              Inflacion)

x1=as.matrix(X1)
x2=as.matrix(X2)  

 
#Definimos la función de verosimilitud
##########################################################
fmv <- function(y,xa,xb,sigma1,sigma2,
                a1,a2,a3,a4,a5,
                b1,b2,b3,b4 ) {
  beta1 <- data.frame(a1,a2,a3,a4,a5)
  beta2 <- data.frame(b1,b2,b3,b4)
  f1 <- 1/sqrt(2*pi*sigma1^2 ) * exp(-1/(2*sigma1^2 )*(Ct-x1%*%t(beta1))^2)
  f2 <- 1/sqrt(2*pi*sigma2^2 ) * exp(-1/(2*sigma2^2 )*(Ct-x2%*%t(beta2))^2)
  F1 <- numeric(nrow(Ct))
  F2 <- numeric(nrow(Ct))
  for (i in 1:nrow(Ct)){
    F1[i] <- pnorm(Ct[i,1], x1[i,]%*%t(beta1), sigma1, lower.tail = F)
    F2[i] <- pnorm(Ct[i,1], x2[i,]%*%t(beta2), sigma2, lower.tail = F)
  }
  -sum(log((f1*F2)+(f2*F1)),log=TRUE)
}


#PARAMETROS INICIALES MCO
summary(FIT <-
          lm(VarCredito~FonDisp+TAE+TasaMora+PrecioPet+IDEAC+-1))

summary(FIT2 <- lm(VarCredito~TAE+Paro+IPIM+Inflacion+-1))

plot(VarCredito,type="o",col="black")
lines(predict(FIT),type="o",col="blue")
lines(predict(FIT2),type="o",col="red")



#FUNCION MCO
fmc <- function(y,xa,xb,
                a1,a2,a3,a4,a5,
                b1,b2,b3,b4 ) {
  beta1 <- data.frame(a1,a2,a3,a4,a5)
  beta2 <- data.frame(b1,b2,b3,a4)
  sum((Ct-pmin(x1%*%t(beta1),x2%*%t(beta2), log=TRUE))^2)
}


library("bbmle")
class(Ct[,1])

p<-mle2(fmc,start=list(a1= -0.000003533,a2=0.009015,a3=-0.5944,a4=0.03418,a5=0.00001512,
                       b1= -0.0112861,b2= 0.6571781,b3= 0.0006255,b4= 0.0021346),
        data=list(y=Ct,xa=x1,xb=x2))

summary(p)
########################################################## 
#Tomamos 100 valores iniciales aleatorios con media los obtenidos por MCO 
##########################################################
asigma1<-rnorm(100,0.035,0.026) 
asigma2<-rnorm(100,0.035,0.026) 
aa1<-rnorm(100,coef(p)[1],1) 
aa2<-rnorm(100,coef(p)[2],1) 
aa3<-rnorm(100,coef(p)[3],0.0001) 
aa4<-rnorm(100,coef(p)[4], 0.0001) 
aa5<-rnorm(100,coef(p)[5],1)
ab1<-rnorm(100,coef(p)[6],1) 
ab2<-rnorm(100,coef(p)[7],0.0001) 
ab3<-rnorm(100,coef(p)[8],1)
ab4<-rnorm(100,coef(p)[9],0.0001)


#Vemos cuál de estos valores iniciales nos da una verosimilitud más alta
L <- numeric(100) 
for (i in 1:100){ 
m <- logLik(mle2(fmv,start=list(sigma1=asigma1[i],sigma2=asigma2[i], 
a1=aa1[i],a2=aa2[i],a3=aa3[i],a4=aa4[i],a5=aa5[i], 
b1=ab1[i],b2=ab2[i],b3=ab3[i],b4=ab4[i]), 
data=list(y=Ct,xa=x1,xb=x2))) 
L[i] <-m[1] 
}
```

Posteriormente debo aplicar which.max(L), pero el error se genera en L y no me deja. Todas las variables son numéricas.

Comment: Que diga `only defined on a data frame with all numeric variables` da a pensar que crees que todas las variables son numéricas pero realmente no lo son. Eso es lo que habría que revisar. Errores similares reportados tienen que ver con cosas simples como problemas en los row_names o en los datos mismos (que de ahí no sale)

Comment: He revisado parte por parte de la función de verosimilitud fmv, el problema es que en -sum(log((f1*F2)+(f2*F1)),log=TRUE), la suma (f1*F2)+(f2*F1) me genera números negativos y no es posible calcular el logaritmo. En mi base de datos tengo números negativos porque uso tasas de variación como variables y no puedo omitir las tasas negativas porque no obtendría los resultados correctos.

Comment: ¿Cual es la sentencia en particular que e da el error?

Comment: @PatricioMoracho dice que la última, pero el mensaje habla del llamado a logLik

Comment: @Alfabravo, quisiera descartar que sea el llamado explícito a `logLik` o código relacionado a `mle2` (que internamente llama a `logLik`)

Comment: @PatricioMoracho, @Alfabravo, gracias por su tiempo, he logrado resolver el error, al parecer en f1 cuando la función calcula exp genera INF como resultado porque los números son muy grandes, se corrigió añadiendo la función `mprf`

Comment: Ponlo como respuesta, ojalá con el fragmento de código para que otros puedan venir y resolver este mismo problema. Después puedes marcar la respuesta como aceptada también.

Answer (score 1):

He logrado resolver el error, al parecer en f1 cuando la función calcula `exp` genera **INF** como resultado porque los números son muy grandes, se corrigió añadiendo la función `mprf`y luego calculando `exp`